# Separate by blank lines in bash

Tags: shell, lines

I have an input like this:

```
Block 1:
line1
line2
line3
line4

Block 2:
line1
line2

Block 3:
line1
line2
line3
```

This is an example, is there an elegant way to print Block 2 and its lines only without rely on their names? It would be like "separate the blocks by the blank line and print the second block".

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 awk '!$0{i++;next;}i==1' yourFile
```

considering performance, also can add exit after 2nd block was processed:

```
 awk '!$0{i++;next;}i==1;i>1{exit;}' yourFile
```

**test**:

```
kent$  cat t
Block 1:
line1
line2
line3
line4

Block 2:
line1
line2

Block 3:
line1
line2
line3

kent$  awk '!$0{i++;next;}i==1' t           
Block 2:
line1
line2

kent$  awk '!$0{i++;next;}i==1;i>1{exit;}' t
Block 2:
line1
line2
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the record separater to the empty string to separate on blank lines.  To
print the second block:

```
$ awk -v RS=  'NR==2{ print }'
```

(Note that this only separates on lines that do not contain any whitespace.
A line containing only white space is not considered a blank line.)

Comment: +1, I didn't know that about RS. Might as well add `exit` into the print block.

Comment: Perl equivalent: `perl -00 -ne 'if ($.==2) {print; exit}'`

Comment: I have tried this approach before and didn't work, now I see that I have 1 white space on each "blank" line!

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Did you just downvote this answer?  May I inquire as to why?