# How do I split a text file into an array by blank lines?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, awk

I have a bash command that outputs text in the following format:

```
Header 1
- Point 1
- Point 2

Header 2
- Point 1
- Point 2

Header 3
-Point 1
- Point 2

...
```

I want to parse this text into an array, separating on the empty line so that array[0] for example contains:

```
Header 1
- Point 1
- Point 2
```

And then I want to edit some of the data in the array if it satisfies certain conditions.

I was looking at something like this [Separate by blank lines in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892256/separate-by-blank-lines-in-bash) but I'm completely new to bash so I don't understand how to save the output from awk RS=null to an array instead of printing it out. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? This sounds very much XY to me.

Comment: I have a tool that generates data in the format I stated above (text separated into chunks by empty lines). I want to get an array of the chunks so that I can iterate the array to mutate the data in each one (e.g. if a chunk satisfies condition A do a certain action, otherwise do something else etc.). In the end, I want to print all of the data after the mutations.

Comment: That is what I meant with an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you would tell us the conditions, we could probably help you writing a single awk program that does the task for you in a single go. Nonetheless, disregarding this, your question is very nice and the answer given is excellent. Have a look at [Someone Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `readarray` command to populate a bash array after reading your file with gnu `awk` command with empty `RS` that lets `awk` split records on empty lines and using `ORS` as `\0` (NUL) byte:

```
IFS= readarray -d '' arr < <(awk -v RS= -v ORS='\0' '1' file)
```

Check output:

```
echo "${arr[0]}"
Header 1
- Point 1
- Point 2

echo "${arr[1]}"
Header 2
- Point 1
- Point 2

echo "${arr[2]}"
Header 3
-Point 1
- Point 2
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/H6Aa4P)

Comment: @anubhava is `mapfile` preferred over `readarray`, which has a more intuitive name?

Comment: For me `readarray` is more intuitive though it is a synonym for `mapfile`. But I get your point, editing it to `readarray`

Comment: test.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `<' 
test.sh: line 6: `  IFS= readarray -d '' arr < <(awk -v RS= -v ORS='\0' '1' output.txt)'`

@anubhava I'm getting this error after I copied that line of code. But it is working for you?

Comment: Make sure you use `bash` as it uses `bash` syntax.

Comment: @anubhava It is not working for me, looks like all of the text goes into arr[0] only. Any ideas? (Thanks for all of your help so far by the way, much appreciated)

Comment: This requires `gnu-awk`. Please check your awk version.